# Azure Durable Functions - OrchestrationTrigger continuously executing 1st awaited Activity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created an [Azure Durable Function](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/index.html) following the structure of the [Fan-out / Fan-In](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/samples/cloud-backup.html) example, (using the recommended VS 2017 development, not the Azure Portal approach)

What I am experiencing is that very the first Azure Function that is called from the `OrchestrationTrigger` method is called over and over again, and never continues to the next statement. Now while I have read the Event Sourcing, Checkpointing, and Orchestrator Replay documentation and the [Orchestrator Code Constraints](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/overview.html#orchestrator-code-constraints), I am still a bit confused as debugging locally is very tricky due to the replay.

```
[FunctionName("ExportLogs")]
public static async Task ExportLogs([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    SinceDate since = context.GetInput<SinceDate>();
    var sinceDate = DateTime.Parse(since.since);

    var conversationInfos = await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<ConversationInfo>>("GetConversations", sinceDate);

    // !! I never get to this statement
    var tasks = new List<Task<CallInfo>>(conversationInfos.Count());
    foreach (var ci in conversationInfos)
    {
        Task<CallInfo> task = context.CallActivityAsync<CallInfo>("ProcessCall", ci);
        task.Start();
        var notused = task.ContinueWith(t => context.CallActivityAsync("PersistCallInStorage", t.Result));
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // Now fan-in and persist all results.
    var callInfos = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    var repo = new DwRepository(connectionString);
    repo.AddCallInfos(callInfos);
}
```

The first activity called is:

```
[FunctionName("GetConversations")]
public static IEnumerable<ConversationInfo> GetConversations([ActivityTrigger] DateTime sinceDate, TraceWriter log)
{
    var exportService = ConstuctExportService();
    var conversations = exportService.GetAllConversations(sinceDate);
    return conversations;
}
```

Now, `exportService.GetAllConversations(sinceDate);` is calling upon an SDK that is fetching some call information from a cloud service via REST. It does need to loop and fetch the data in pages. So what is happening is that this get called over and over and never continues on, even though I am awaiting the call.

Here is the output from the Function Runtime output window:

```
[10/23/2017 7:25:43 PM] Function started (Id=8e62e6bd-34a9-49b7-a814-3a0e9e5f9f8e)
[10/23/2017 7:25:43 PM] Executing 'ExportRscCallLogs' (Reason='', Id=8e62e6bd-34a9-49b7-a814-3a0e9e5f9f8e)
[10/23/2017 7:25:43 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'ExportRscCallLogs (Orchestrator)', version '' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (22 bytes). State: Started. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' scheduled. Reason: ExportRscCallLogs. IsReplay: False. State: Scheduled. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] Function completed (Success, Id=8e62e6bd-34a9-49b7-a814-3a0e9e5f9f8e, Duration=114ms)
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] Executed 'ExportRscCallLogs' (Succeeded, Id=8e62e6bd-34a9-49b7-a814-3a0e9e5f9f8e)
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'ExportRscCallLogs (Orchestrator)', version '' awaited. IsReplay: False. State: Awaited. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (23 bytes). State: Started. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] Function started (Id=3c33ff3b-5fe5-4e6b-a7d4-ac6c3e146633)
[10/23/2017 7:25:44 PM] Executing 'GetConversations' (Reason='', Id=3c33ff3b-5fe5-4e6b-a7d4-ac6c3e146633)
[10/23/2017 7:25:47 PM] Function completed (Success, Id=3c33ff3b-5fe5-4e6b-a7d4-ac6c3e146633, Duration=2824ms)
[10/23/2017 7:25:47 PM] Executed 'GetConversations' (Succeeded, Id=3c33ff3b-5fe5-4e6b-a7d4-ac6c3e146633)
[10/23/2017 7:25:47 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (435216 bytes). State: Completed. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:25:54 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (23 bytes). State: Started. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:25:54 PM] Function started (Id=d89b2fa4-f4d7-43e5-95f1-5cf436ebc85e)
[10/23/2017 7:25:54 PM] Executing 'GetConversations' (Reason='', Id=d89b2fa4-f4d7-43e5-95f1-5cf436ebc85e)
[10/23/2017 7:25:56 PM] Function completed (Success, Id=d89b2fa4-f4d7-43e5-95f1-5cf436ebc85e, Duration=1397ms)
[10/23/2017 7:25:56 PM] Executed 'GetConversations' (Succeeded, Id=d89b2fa4-f4d7-43e5-95f1-5cf436ebc85e)
[10/23/2017 7:25:56 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (435216 bytes). State: Completed. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:26:05 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (23 bytes). State: Started. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
[10/23/2017 7:26:05 PM] Function started (Id=fb240d9c-90f0-4e4d-86db-b3d2c175e0eb)
[10/23/2017 7:26:05 PM] Executing 'GetConversations' (Reason='', Id=fb240d9c-90f0-4e4d-86db-b3d2c175e0eb)
[10/23/2017 7:26:06 PM] Function completed (Success, Id=fb240d9c-90f0-4e4d-86db-b3d2c175e0eb, Duration=1177ms)
[10/23/2017 7:26:06 PM] Executed 'GetConversations' (Succeeded, Id=fb240d9c-90f0-4e4d-86db-b3d2c175e0eb)
[10/23/2017 7:26:06 PM] b350f681b17b4ac8a772fff8fdca3aad: Function 'GetConversations (Activity)', version '' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (435216 bytes). State: Completed. HubName: DurableFunctionsHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 1.0.0.0.
```

As you can see, the logs are showing that it is `Executing 'GetConversations'` over and over again, and it even reports that it was completed successfully each time. The `IsReplay` parameter is False - so I am not sure what's going on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is odd. A couple questions:
1. How are you triggering the orchestrator function?
2. Assuming you're running locally, do you see any interesting exceptions if you configure VS to break on first-chance exceptions?

Comment: **1)** Triggering the orchestrator function using the same approach as in the sample - that is, an HTTP trigger  method with the `[OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter`, pram. which invokes via `string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(functionName, eventData);`

**2)** No exceptions are caught when I have enabled to break when any CLR exception is thrown, while the `GetConversations` function is continuously called.

Comment: Also note that before every attempt, I clear out the contents of the `durablefunctionshub-leases` blob storage, all of the `durablefunctionshub-control-0x` and `durablefunctionshub-workitems` queues, as well as the `DurableFunctionsHubHistory` table.

Comment: Would you mind opening an issue on GitHub? That will make it easier to track and share information. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues

Comment: Done. [Issue 79](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/79) created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Chris Gillum's efforts in identifying the problem on the posted [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/79). He discovered that my initial activity is

> returning back a relatively large amount of data (482564 bytes, or 471
>   KB). Return values get serialized into queue messages, and [Azure
>   storage queues only support 64 KB messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#capacity-and-quotas). I suspect the runtime is
>   not handling this gracefully and is resulting in it running
>   continuously.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this reply as the correct answer. :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark this reply as the correct answer. :)